# Is there a limit to the number of gmaps comments viewed by users?

Tags: ajax, selenium, google-maps, web-scraping

I want to **scrape** the reviews from google maps by selenium, and one of the steps is to scroll down gmaps web page to get more comments' requests. But when it reached about comment 900,the web page stuck,keep showing the loading image.
I also scroll the page by myself,and got the same result,plz help me,thanks a lot!!

[where the comment from](https://www.google.com.tw/maps/place/%E4%BA%94%E5%AF%AE%E5%B0%96%E5%B1%B1/@24.8772967,121.3477454,14z/data=!4m11!1m2!2m1!1z5LqU5a-u5bCW!3m7!1s0x34681a19e369b28f:0x44dfa33c149378f!8m2!3d24.8768431!4d121.3656277!9m1!1b1!15sCgnkupTlr67lsJaSAQtzY2VuaWNfc3BvdA?hl=zh-TW&authuser=0)

[loadind image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OamE.png)

this is how I scroll the page

```
for i in range(scroll_times):
    time.sleep(delay)
    scroll_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.section-scrollbox') #find scroll box  
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight',scroll_box)#scroll to the bottom
    review_text = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ODSEW-ShBeI-text")
    print(len(review_text))
```

Comment: Is the problem with your script or with the Google page? According to the description, it is an issue with the Google page not loading further reviews. Maybe open a bug and/or contact their support and explain to them what you are trying to do, I am sure they will help!

Comment: @MrUpsidown I think It is a bug from goole chrome, because I change the driver to firefox, then it works,thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` after loading 930 comments. See the screenshot below:

[image: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

I agree with [MrUpsidown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238965) — send a bug report to Google.

---

Open browser dev tools and check actual requests. Send requests directly instead of using Selenium.

Or [scrape Google Maps Reviews](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-reviews-api) via SerpApi.

Example in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@serpapi/scrape-google-maps-place-reviews-serpapi-async)

```py
import os
import logging
import asyncio
from urllib import parse

from serpapi import GoogleSearch

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(thread)s %(message)s"
)


async def main():
    params = {
        "engine": "google_maps",
        "q": "coffee",
        "type": "search",
        "ll": "@40.7455096,-74.0083012,14z",
        "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
    }

    async for result, page_number in paginate(params):
        logging.info(f"Local places results on page #{page_number}")

        for result in result.get("local_results", []):
            data_id = result.get("data_id")

            logging.info(
                f"""
Title: {result.get('title')}
Address: {result.get('address')}
Rating: {result.get('rating')}
Reviews: {result.get('reviews')}"""
            )

            reviews_params = {
                "engine": "google_maps_reviews",
                "hl": "en",
                "data_id": data_id,
                "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
            }

            async for result, page_number in paginate(reviews_params):
                logging.info(
                    f"Local places results on page #{page_number} for place '{data_id}'"
                )

                for review in result.get("reviews", []):
                    logging.info(
                        f"\nRating: {review.get('rating')}\nSnippet: {review.get('snippet')}"
                    )


async def paginate(params, limit=10000):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    client = GoogleSearch(params)

    page_number = 0

    while True:
        # Stop iteration on reaching the desired number of pages
        if page_number > limit:
            break

        result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, client.get_dict)

        pagination = result.get("serpapi_pagination", result.get("pagination", {}))

        # stop if no next page
        if not "next" in pagination:
            break

        params_from_target_website = dict(
            parse.parse_qsl(parse.urlsplit(pagination["next"]).query)
        )

        # stop if parameters from the target website were not changed
        if params_from_target_website.items() <= client.params_dict.items():
            break

        client.params_dict.update(params_from_target_website)

        page_number += 1

        yield result, page_number


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output

```
Local places results on page #6 for place '0x89c259aaf9f37add:0x186bfd80c2bf7095'

Rating: 5.0
Snippet: My favorite coffee at Bryant Park! Small dark roast, every time!

Rating: 1.0
Snippet: I ordered latte and requested two shots of coffee, my latte was not strong enough and when I asked them to make it stronger, they asked for extra charge.
```

Video explanation: https://youtu.be/PvKG7upRBjI

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*

Comment: I solved the problem by changing to another driver ,thank you for let me know what actually happened !